# What is the best way to represent department email addresses in companies where there exists turnover?

Tags: email

Currently, we have email addresses, such as the following addresses:

- designer@company.com
- operation1@company.com
- operation2@company.com
- bookings@operation.com

Should department addresses be something like design@company.com, or should they use the names of real people in that department, such as john@company.com or helen@company.com? Please explain why.

What would be better in a scenario where people leave the company, for example? What is the best way to represent department email addresses?

Comment: Hi Herr, welcome to the Workplace SE! I edited your post to focus more on the important parts of your question and clarified the title so it focuses on explanations instead of just simply listing pros/cons. We strive to formulate questions so that answers explain why and how. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hey @jmort253, thank you very much :) Although I gave my best to formulate a good question I really appreciate your time and effort to do so. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How should a departments email addresses look like?

The answer depends on how you intend to use these departmental emails.

Many companies have departmental email lists like "Support@companyname.com" designed to forward the emails to everyone in the department (even if only a department of one). When an individual leaves, that person's individual email address is simply dropped from the email list and replaced with the individual email address of the replacement.

Sometimes, if the email address is used externally, and the company wishes to project a "friendly face", a fictitious name is used in the email. One company I worked for used something like "Sally@companyname.com" as an email alias for the Customer Support team mail list.

Almost every company also has individual email addresses.

Comment: hmm this looks like the right way

Comment: To add: And when someone leaves, forward the mail from his (her) email address to the person taking over his responsibilities. When that person replies, his *from* email adress is on the mail, so the old email adress will fade out gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

The most common I see as well currently using in my current job is

department@company-uk.org

first.lastname@company-uk.org

receptionatlocation@company-uk.org

These are the main ones that are used constantly internal and external. Using the 2nd one is good per person as how many people have the exact same name.

By using a departmental address that everyone can access when someone is to leave they can leave a out of office message stating please email the shared email address where the remaining people can assist you.

Comment: Should there be a combination of 1 and 2?

Comment: What if for example, you have 2 or more designers for the designer@ addresses?

Comment: @HerrK Do you mean like michaelgrubeysoftwaredevelopment@company-uk.org? Thats a really long Email address..

Comment: @HerrK Every person has their own Email address and have seperate ones setup that people can have access to so shared mailboxes.

Comment: no not really. The current problem we are facing is, email accounts are created incrementally like designer1, designer2 & etc.

Comment: @HerrK If each person has a personal mailbox - if they already do then rename them to firstname.lastname@____ and then setup new ones that everyone has access to so they can send on behalf of shared mailbox. If they need to send something personally then they have their own.

Comment: I think that's the proper solution!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10445/discussion-between-michael-grubey-and-herr-k)

Answer (score 0):

Generally we do both. We use the general ones for things that we sent in an automated way such as emails from successful or failed databases imports or for things that we might want a group of people to have access to. Then we forward those to the individuals concerned. But everyone also has a direct personal email for the majority of the work where they need to be contacted directly.

Comment: Hmm pretty interesting. Are the more general accounts monitored by individuals too?